# Increasing a number when clicking on a button with $ sign still in it

Tags: javascript

so I'm rubbing my head over this and I can't seem to figure it out how to increment the number by 1 while having a $ sign. Please help :(
HTML

```
    <section id="jackpot-container">
    <div id="jackpot">$200</div>    
</section>

<section id="buttons-container">
    <button id="increase-button" class="button">Add $1</button>
</section>
```

Comment: so where is addition code ?

Answer (score 3):

You first need to remove the `$` sign, convert the data into a numeric value (an integer) and add `1`, then add back the `$` sign and show it to the user, like this:

```js
document.getElementById('increase-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let val = document.getElementById('jackpot').textContent;
  val = parseInt(val.replace('$', '')) + 1;
  document.getElementById('jackpot').innerHTML = '$' + val;
});
```

```html
<section id="jackpot-container">
  <div id="jackpot">$200</div>
</section>

<section id="buttons-container">
  <button id="increase-button" class="button">Add $1</button>
</section>
```

Comment: While retrieving text, you are using `textContent ` but while assigning, why are you using `innerHTML` ?

Comment: @Rayon force of habit mostly. The issue with `innerHTML` is that retrieving it might not result in a clean enough value sometimes depending on markup and format. You could use `textContent` for both honestly.